# Total label on chart x-axis

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivot table containing a user name with item names and quantity within it (eg: User "Alan" has 10 of "Hat" and 5 of "Coat", to keep it simple).

In the generated pivot chart column graph, instead of just the x-axis label "Alan",  is it possible to display "Total items for Alan: 15"? How would this be coded?

Comment: One quick way is to put this in a cell, say `A1` `="Total items for Alan: " & [sum of values to equal 15]`. Then click the Chart Title box, and just type `=A1`.  Then whatever `A1` says, the chart Title will update to that.  AFAIK you can't save a step and put `="Total Items for Alan: " & B1` in the chart title formula, it'll throw an error.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of what it currently looks like and then what you want it to look like?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. You gave me a good idea with the A1 cell suggestion and it works great (I should have thought of that too). Thanks again.